# Android - report app errors / crashed programmatically

Tags: java, android, google-play

In an Android app, when it is a version downloaded from Google Play, when the app crashed suddenly there is an option to "Report" the bug and the stacktrace is then visible in Google Play Developer Console (which is a great feature by the way). I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow programmatically report the bug in the same way? For instance if I catch an exception in my code and want to show to the user the message that an error occurred and allows him to e.g. press the button to report it (the same as that one which reports a bug to Google Play)?
I suppose it's not possible to provide the same functionality as that GP bug reporting functionality. If so, what is the best way to handle that?

Comment: That one seems great :). I will check it. thank you!

Comment: Search for fabric crashlytics android